# How to create On/Off animation like in Time Machine?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am creating a preference pane for our software and I want to create an on/off animation much like the timemachine in the preference pane. Any ideas how?

Comment: xcode is an IDE. has nothing to do with it. retagged.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you mean the On/Off button like the one you find in iPhone apps? There is an Open Source component called PRHOnOffButton that you might be able to use.

http://cocoaobjects.com/prhonoffbutton/